# Compatibility of (legacy) Sun Hardware?

Tags: linux, hardware, sun, cross-platform

I have a couple (well a lot more than that..but for the sake of the brevity.) of sun enterprise 250 servers with solaris installed on them. I want to know if any version/flavor/distro of linux can be installed on it

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Enterprise

I've heard from some folks that its impossible, But I wondered if there were some kinda trick or kernel recompilation that would allow me to install and run Linux on sun hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/SPARC) working on it. spot can probably give you more details.

Answer (score 2):

E250's are sun4u so you have a chance of getting Debian running on them. Have a look at the [Debian sparc](http://www.debian.org/ports/sparc/) page.

There is also some information in SUN/Oracles's [UltraLinux](http://web.archive.org/web/20080917183148/http://www.sun.com/software/linux/compatibility/ultralinux/) pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely get at least some version of debian running on them. Alternatively, you could try FreeBSD or netBSD which may be more current.